# adding element to end of array in sharedObject

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I want to add an element to an array with every click button.

I used shared Object. because i'm going to call my data after i reopen my app.

how can i define an array in shared object?

i cant use this:

```
myData.data.list = [];
```

since when i open my application again, my last data will be deleted.

and how can i add elements to my variable in shared object?
i tried this:

> ```
> Array(myData.data.list).push(number);
> ```

but when i trace that, every index of that is still undefined and nothing has changed.

what's the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this steps:

First ActionScript code to create an Array, and push the element in the Array. and finally stored Array in ShraedObject. SharedObject is stored disk. so it will probably be in the form of ByteArray. so read and the data type must be converted to match.

If you want write to a Array in SharedObject

```
var myArray:Array = [obj1, obj2...];
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("myArray");
so.data.myArrayData = myArray;
so.flush();
```

To retrieve it back anywhere and adding element to end of array. and resaved.

```
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("myArray");
var myArray:Array = so.data.myArrayData;
myArray.push(number);
so.data.myArrayData = myArray;
so.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found something helpful that I'm going to add into the above code answer:

```
To retrieve it back anywhere and adding element to end of array. and resaved.

var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("myArray","/");
var myArray:Array = so.data.myArrayData;
myArray.push(number);
so.data.myArrayData = myArray;
so.flush();
```

To avoid inadvertently restricting access to a shared object, ***use the localpath parameter.*** - which is the "/"